# mongo choose another index for query

Tags: mongodb

I have the following indexes in mongodb:

```
a_1
a_1_b_1
a_1_b_1_c_1
```

when I find a document (all documents have a,b,c fields) with the query 'db.collection.find({"a":1}).explain()' mongo use as winning plan the index a_1_b_1. why MongoDB chooses that index instead of a_1 ?

All documents:

> db.messages1.find()

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a1926718d36336a82b88692"), "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a19267b8d36336a82b88693"), "a" : 7, "b" : 6, "c" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a1926838d36336a82b88694"), "a" : 9, "b" : 1, "c" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a19268b8d36336a82b88695"), "a" : 0, "b" : 10, "c" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a1926918d36336a82b88696"), "a" : 1, "b" : 10, "c" : 51 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a1926e28d36336a82b88697"), "a" : 5, "b" : 2, "c" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a1926ea8d36336a82b88698"), "a" : 11, "b" : 21, "c" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a1926ee8d36336a82b88699"), "a" : 11, "b" : 21, "c" : 28 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a1947718d36336a82b8869a"), "a" : 1, "b" : 3, "c" : 9 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a1947828d36336a82b8869b"), "a" : 1, "b" : 31, "c" : 9 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a1947888d36336a82b8869c"), "a" : 1, "b" : 32, "c" : 9 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a19478c8d36336a82b8869d"), "a" : 1, "b" : 34, "c" : 9 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a1947908d36336a82b8869e"), "a" : 1, "b" : 37, "c" : 9 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a1947948d36336a82b8869f"), "a" : 1, "b" : 39, "c" : 9 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a1947988d36336a82b886a0"), "a" : 1, "b" : 41, "c" : 9 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a1947c38d36336a82b886a1"), "a" : 2, "b" : 0, "c" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a1947c88d36336a82b886a2"), "a" : 2, "b" : 0, "c" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a1947cb8d36336a82b886a3"), "a" : 2, "b" : 0, "c" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a1947cd8d36336a82b886a4"), "a" : 2, "b" : 0, "c" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a1947d08d36336a82b886a5"), "a" : 2, "b" : 0, "c" : 5 }
```

db.collection.find({"a":1}).explain()

Comment: hi, @MrElefant, can you show a sample doc and a sample query?

Comment: Are you asking why MongoDB chooses that index, or are you asking how to force MongoDB to choose another index for the query?

Comment: why MongoDB chooses that index?